# Spring Security Password Encoder is working just by creating a bean and without calling inside any method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I created a password encoder bean and I am just calling passwordEncoder.encode() method in UserService -> createUser() method. But how spring is understanding that "I have to use password encoder when login request came". I am not passing passwordEncoder as an argument anywhere.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class SecurityConfig {

private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;
private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
private final JWTAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;


@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}


@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                auth.antMatchers("/api/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
                auth.antMatchers("/api/user").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER");
                auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();

}

@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/public", "/h2-console/**", "/api/auth/login");
}

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedMethods("*");
        }
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The default password encoder in Spring delegates to any defined beans of type `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder`.  So Spring is simply delegating to the bean that you provided.

Comment: thank you so much. In some tutorials, some people are giving password encoder manually to AuthenticationManagerBuilder or DaoAuthenticationProvider. So I little bit confused.

Comment: And you can certainly do that.  Also, note that the AuthenticationProvider bean that Spring is constructing to handle the authentication, injects a bean of type `PasswordEncoder`, as you've provided this bean as `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, this is getting injected for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the code here

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/AuthenticationConfiguration.java#L332

You would see that Spring actually injects the bean `PasswordEncoder` from the current `applicationContext`

So as you see creating this bean is what the Spring security calls when encoding the password coming into the `AuthenticationManager`